# Property attribute of Setter in VisualState.Setters generates syntax error

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to make a custom style for my UWP button. So I copied the [button style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx) from MSDN and then **only** modified the `"PointerOver"` Visual State to make sure I got the gist of it.

Below is a snippet what I have so far. It is in a separate file called `CustomButtonStyleTemplate.xaml` and in my main xaml file I imported it using `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries/>`.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SpecialButton">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="ButtonGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="ButtonGrid.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

Unfortunately, My custom `<Setter/>` is generating the following error: `The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error`.

Whenever I look for similar code online, most people set the `Property` field of the `<Setter/>` to something like `MyButton.Opacity`, where some `<Button/>` element has `x:Name="MyButton"`.

The thing is, I want this style to apply to *many* buttons that I will *explicitly* choose, hence why I specified `x:Key="SpecialButton"` for the `<Style/>`.

I thought since the `<Grid/>` has `x:Name="ButtonGrid"`, I should use `ButtonGrid.Opacity` but clearly I am mistaken.  I should note that `ButtonGrid.(UIElement.Opacity)` didn't work either.

How then should I refer generically to the `Opacity` property of which ever button this style applies to?

Comment: try this: `<Setter Target="ButtonGrid.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>`

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman's suggestion was correct. Please note that if you change the name of Grid as "ButtonGrid", you also need to change all "RootGrid" to "ButtonGrid" in this style. Because in this style , the "RootGrid" is used in other visual states. It will cause exception when the other visual state is triggered.

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman You could make an answer on this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Property="ButtonGrid.Opacity"` to `Target="ButtonGrid.Opacity"` .

Like this:

```
<Setter Target="ButtonGrid.Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!